# Sentence meaning "gone and conditioned myself"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading fanfic in English and I don't understand what is selected sentence?

> I’ve developed a problem. Jerking off in silence is depressing so I’ve
>   been keeping the music on a bit. This means that almost every session
>   has a soundtrack of Disco because the Beatles is just sacrilege.
>   Yesterday when I was in the rover and put some tunes on, instant
>   hardon. **I’ve only fucking gone and conditioned myself.** It’s now a
>   classic Pavlovian response - Disco equals erection. I am going to have
>   to break this cycle or I’m going to be a complete disgrace at
>   weddings.

What does it mean?

Comment: That's intriguing, as a Russian, didn't you ever hear of  [Pavlov](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning) effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "condition" someone or something is to get them to expect something when something else happens. As @LucianSava says, the classic example is the Pavlov effect: a dog heard a bell, expected food, so salivated - a previously assumed unconscious reaction, yet here it was happening according to conscious thought.

So when the protagonist now hears Disco, he gets an otherwise unconscious reaction: he's conditioned to hearing Disco and expecting the next step.

The word "gone" here is used in the frustrated sense:

- "Our alcoholic aunt has only gone and got herself arrested for drunk driving!"
- "I wanted to quit smoking, but I've gone and bought another pack."